# React typescript spread props when component extends interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a router object that maps all routes to `Route` components:

```
<Router history={history}>
      <App>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(route => (
            <AuthRoute exact {...route}
          ))}
          <Redirect to={'/'} from={'*'} />
        </Switch>
      </App>
    </Router>
```

But since `AuthRoute` is an interface that looks like this:

```
interface AuthRouteType {
    component: typeof Component,
    route: RouteType,
    exact: boolean
    name: string
}
```

When I do spread props I get an error that I have some missing parameters.

How can do spread props when using an interface?

Comment: I think there must be something missing above, shouldn't there be a `/>` at the end of the `<AuthRoute` line? (Indentation seems wonky as well.)

Comment: This AuthRoute is your component and the AuthRouteType is the interface for the props for the AuthRoute component? Also what types are stored in routes?